# Problem in multi booting Ubuntu 12.04 with existing Windows XP, 7 and 8 in 500GB HDD with 5 Partitions

Tags: windows, partitioning, dual-boot, boot-partition

Here's my case. I have  500GB HDD with 5 Partitions with XP, Windows7 and Windows8 RP in the first three.

As per one of the instruction I've seen in this forum, I did shrink my 4th Partition to create a 30GB unallocated free space to install Ubuntu 12.04. But, when next I'm trying to boot the Ubuntu CD and choosing "Something Else", its only recognizing my 500GB HDD in whole as "/sda" and not reading the free 30GB space separately to install Ubuntu in it as suggested in the instruction mentioned in this forum.

I've also tried to install in from within Windows7, by mounting the Ubuntu ISO file and using the .exe file and instruction thereupon (choosing free drive, user name, installation size, etc.), but that also failed after the PC restarted to continue the installation, showing as error for file extension, partition something error.

One thing to be noted that the PC I'm trying to install Ubuntu in it is my Home PC and doesn't have any internet connection. Hence, no updates or otherwise online help.

What shall I do?? Kindly suggest.

Sorry if I made some grammatical mistakes as English is not my first language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may help if you say which instructions you have seen and are following, please post links. Are you able to use the Ubuntu applications Disk Utility from the CD and gparted ?
You will be wanting to format the partition, or partitions that Ubuntu will be using. I am a newbie with Ubuntu, but do have it working on CDs a Memory Stick and installed on two multi booting Windows computers. The laptop I am using now has only a single hdd. I did have a big advantage of having online instructions to hand.
Maybe if you are unable to have online information to hand you can copy the information whilst o

Answer (score 1):

Installing Ubuntu on partitioned drive same as making bootable usb flash drive.
Look this site: [*Making a bootable USB of Ubuntu*](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/usb)
Obviously, this partition should be marked as Removable Media, and you should be able to boot from this media.

*If you want install Ubuntu from CD, better way is an additional separate drive for this task.*